# How to pick an element from matrix (list of list in python) based on decision variables (one for row, and one for column) | OR-Tools, Python

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I am new to constraint programming and OR-Tools. A brief about the problem. There are 8 positions, for each position I need to decide which move of type A (move_A) and which move of type B (move_B) should be selected such that the value achieved from the combination of the 2 moves (at each position) is maximized. (This is only a part of the bigger problem though). And I want to use `AddElement` approach to do the sub setting.

Please see the below attempt

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# value achieved from combination of different moves of type A
# (moves_A (rows)) and different moves of type B (moves_B (columns))
# for e.g. 2nd move of type A and 3rd move of type B will give value = 2
value = [
            [ -1,  5,  3,  2,  2],
            [  2,  4,  2, -1,  1], 
            [  4,  4,  0, -1,  2],
            [  5,  1, -1,  2,  2],
            [  0,  0,  0,  0, 0],
            [  2,  1,  1,  2, 0]
       ]

# 6 moves of type A
num_moves_A = len(value)

# 5 moves of type B
num_moves_B = len(value[0])

num_positions = 8

type_move_A_position = [model.NewIntVar(0, num_moves_A - 1, f"move_A[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)]

type_move_B_position = [model.NewIntVar(0, num_moves_B - 1, f"move_B[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)]

value_position = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10, f"value_position[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)]

# I am getting an error when I run the below
objective_terms = []
for i in range(num_positions):
    model.AddElement(type_move_B_position[i], value[type_move_A_position[i]], value_position[i])
    objective_terms.append(value_position[i])
```

The error is as follows:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-3696379ce410>", line 3, in <module>
    model.AddElement(type_move_B_position[i], value[type_move_A_position[i]], value_position[i])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not IntVar
```

In MiniZinc the below code would have worked

```
var int: obj = sum(i in 1..num_positions ) (value [type_move_A_position[i], type_move_B_position[i]])
```

I know in OR-Tools we will have to create some intermediary variables to store results first, so the above approach of minizinc will not work. But I am struggling to do so.

I can always create a 2 matrix of binary binary variables one for num_moves_A * num_positions and the other for num_moves_B * num_positions, add re;evant constraints and achieve the purpose

But I want to learn how to do the same thing via `AddElement` constraint

Any help on how to re-write the `AddElement` snippet is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AddElement is 1D only.
The way it is translated from minizinc to CP-SAT is to create an intermediate variable `p == index1 * max(index2) + index2` and use it in an element constraint with a flattened matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much Laurent for the prompt response. I was able to follow you advice, and it solved my problem. I will post the solution below, in case if it may help somebody with a similar question going forward. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Following Laurent's suggestion (using `AddElement` constraint):

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

# value achieved from combination of different moves of type A
# (moves_A (rows)) and different moves of type B (moves_B (columns))
# for e.g. 2 move of type A and 3 move of type B will give value = 2

value = [
    [-1, 5, 3, 2, 2],
    [2, 4, 2, -1, 1],
    [4, 4, 0, -1, 2],
    [5, 1, -1, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 1, 1, 2, 0],
]

min_value = min([min(i) for i in value])
max_value = max([max(i) for i in value])

# 6 moves of type A
num_moves_A = len(value)

# 5 moves of type B
num_moves_B = len(value[0])

# number of positions
num_positions = 5

# flattened matrix of values
value_flat = [value[i][j] for i in range(num_moves_A) for j in range(num_moves_B)]

# flattened indices
flatten_indices = [
    index1 * len(value[0]) + index2
    for index1 in range(len(value))
    for index2 in range(len(value[0]))
]

type_move_A_position = [
    model.NewIntVar(0, num_moves_A - 1, f"move_A[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)
]

model.AddAllDifferent(type_move_A_position)

type_move_B_position = [
    model.NewIntVar(0, num_moves_B - 1, f"move_B[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)
]

model.AddAllDifferent(type_move_B_position)

# below intermediate decision variable is created which
# will store index corresponding to the selected move of type A and
# move of type B for each position
# this will act as index in the AddElement constraint

flatten_index_num = [
    model.NewIntVar(0, len(flatten_indices), f"flatten_index_num[{i}]")
    for i in range(num_positions)
]

# another intermediate decision variable is created which
# will store value corresponding to the selected move of type A and
# move of type B for each position
# this will act as the target in the AddElement constraint

value_position_index_num = [
    model.NewIntVar(min_value, max_value, f"value_position_index_num[{i}]")
    for i in range(num_positions)
]

objective_terms = []
for i in range(num_positions):
    model.Add(
        flatten_index_num[i]
        == (type_move_A_position[i] * len(value[0])) + type_move_B_position[i]
    )
    model.AddElement(flatten_index_num[i], value_flat, value_position_index_num[i])
    objective_terms.append(value_position_index_num[i])

model.Maximize(sum(objective_terms))

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

solver.ObjectiveValue()

for i in range(num_positions):
    print(
        str(i)
        + "--"
        + str(solver.Value(type_move_A_position[i]))
        + "--"
        + str(solver.Value(type_move_B_position[i]))
        + "--"
        + str(solver.Value(value_position_index_num[i]))
    )
```

Comment: Note you can also use a AllowedAssignment constraint with tuples (i, j, value[i][j])

Comment: Thanks again Laurent. Tried successfully AddAllowedAssignments constraints. This looks more elegant than the AddElement solution (lower number of intermediary decision variables created with AddAllowedAssignments constraints). Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The below version uses `AddAllowedAssignments` constraint to achieve the same purpose (per Laurent's alternate approach) :

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

# value achieved from combination of different moves of type A
# (moves_A (rows)) and different moves of type B (moves_B (columns))
# for e.g. 2 move of type A and 3 move of type B will give value = 2
value = [
    [-1, 5, 3, 2, 2],
    [2, 4, 2, -1, 1],
    [4, 4, 0, -1, 2],
    [5, 1, -1, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 1, 1, 2, 0],
]

min_value = min([min(i) for i in value])
max_value = max([max(i) for i in value])

# 6 moves of type A
num_moves_A = len(value)

# 5 moves of type B
num_moves_B = len(value[0])

# number of positions
num_positions = 5

type_move_A_position = [
    model.NewIntVar(0, num_moves_A - 1, f"move_A[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)
]

model.AddAllDifferent(type_move_A_position)

type_move_B_position = [
    model.NewIntVar(0, num_moves_B - 1, f"move_B[{i}]") for i in range(num_positions)
]

model.AddAllDifferent(type_move_B_position)

value_position = [
    model.NewIntVar(min_value, max_value, f"value_position[{i}]")
    for i in range(num_positions)
]

tuples_list = []
for i in range(num_moves_A):
    for j in range(num_moves_B):
        tuples_list.append((i, j, value[i][j]))

for i in range(num_positions):
    model.AddAllowedAssignments(
        [type_move_A_position[i], type_move_B_position[i], value_position[i]],
        tuples_list,
    )

model.Maximize(sum(value_position))

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

solver.ObjectiveValue()

for i in range(num_positions):
    print(
        str(i)
        + "--"
        + str(solver.Value(type_move_A_position[i]))
        + "--"
        + str(solver.Value(type_move_B_position[i]))
        + "--"
        + str(solver.Value(value_position[i]))
    )
```